# I'm having problems styling a table

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have to build this table layout. Can anybody help me with that?

[image]

I have a dotted border in some columns and also a white border in the header and i don't know how to make the stuff. I'm a bit new with CSS.

Help is very appreciated.

Edit One ----

What i try is that:

```
.my_network_table {

  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: auto;

    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
  table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px 0px;
  }

  thead tr {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
  }

}
```

But the table is far from the expected result.

Comment: try `th{border:none;}`

Comment: How can i make the header background color adjust to the corner radius?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this and I will try to fix it for you?

Comment: Show your HTML markup, too.

Comment: The link: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=d3oLbIUuK9 - 

I don't know why jsfiddle is not showing the style properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helps you,

```
.my_network_table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;

    border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-spacing: 0;}
 tbody td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-right: dotted #ccc;
    border-left: dotted #ccc;
    border-bottom: dotted #ccc;
    border-top: none;
  }
thead td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-collapse:separate;

  }
  thead tr {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
  }

.tdfirst{
     border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;   
}
.tdlast{
     border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;   
}
```

Here is a [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nq2e6sp5/5/)

The fiddle based on your code is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nq2e6sp5/6/)**